# Android BottomNavigationView: too much space between icon and text

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

As of recently the bottom nav bar started to include some strange space between the text and icons (I think after I updated the dependency):

[image]
(Colored red to see the boundaries)

There seems to be a spacer inbetween the icon and text now, which pushes both to the extreme ends of the bar. All I found so far is to use `app:itemPaddingTop` to try and manually push the icons back down, but this breaks the view on smaller devices.

This is the xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/darkGalaxy"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

**Is there some way to make them both centered vertically with minimal margin?**

Basically to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you wrap_content the height with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: @Zain Then the bottom bar just randomly takes up like 80% of the screen, that's why I had to make it 10% of the screen height.

Comment: Not sure of that as couldn't reproduce it, probably something set globally in style file

Comment: Yes, also tried with the constraints and contents go in the middle. There could be a workaround using a custom style with arbitrary multiple lines which tends to get the title much space in below  `<style name="BottomNavigationStyle">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:lines">3</item>` and use it with `android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"`
    </style>`

Comment: @Zain Thank you for your time, I have found the issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

After some testing, I found that it was because of the custom height that I set with `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"`. Stretching the bar higher than it is weirdly spaces the content like this (it wasn't like that when I first made it some months ago).

Anyway, I only had this percentage based height in there, because using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the bottom nav bar made it take up most of the screen. But through the testing I found that this only happened because I was using `android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"`. I cannot remember why I used it, but removing it makes `wrap_content` work.

Comment: removing it doesn't help for me

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, it appears that `app:itemPaddingTop` and `app:itemPaddingBottom` attributes can help to adjust the space between the icon and label inside `BottomNavigationView` item.

Actually, they're just managing space between the top edge of the view and icon, and then the bottom edge and label respectively but that also makes it possible to increase/decrease space between icon and label.